# Web app not validating custom domain name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

Steps I followed:

1. Created an web app (`registration-ceus.azurewebsites.net`)
2. Created a traffic manager profile, added web app as an endpoint (`registrationtmp.trafficmanager.net`) Traffic manager opens the web
   app. Issue I face while adding custom domain. I have own a domain
   (e.g `myworkdomain.net`)
3. I am trying to add subdomain to traffic manager profile (`testregistration.myworkdomain.net`).
   `testregistration.myworkdomain.net` `CNAME`
   `registrationtmp.trafficmanager.net`
4. Added CNAME for my web app:
   `awverify.testregistration.myworkdomain.net` `CNAME`
   `awverify.testregistration.registration-ceus.azurewebsites.net`
5. When trying to add the Custom domain `awverify.testregistration.myworkdomain.net` to my web app, web app
   does not validate the domain name. It always gives option to `Add
   Hostname`.

When I try to access `testregistration.myworkdomain.net`, gets 404 error.
The app service is in Standard tier. What step am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you add `testregistration.myworkdomain.net` as a custom domain on the Web App?

Comment: @juunas I am not able to validate `testregistration.myworkdomain.net` this domain name, it does nothing when I click Validate. Only option is Add Hostname. But if I add the hostname, then it is overriding the traffic manager CNAME.

Comment: Have you followed these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name? Also, what does a `nslookup testregistration.myworkdomain.net` say? Alternatively use `dig` if you're on Linux.

Comment: @kim `nslookup <domain>` gets `Can't find address for server ''`. This error is coming for all domains, which were added 7 days back also.

Comment: Before you can get your custom domain working for your traffic manager, you need to first sort out this DNS issue. Keep in mind that it can take some time before the DNS records have propagated to other DNS servers, tho 7 days should be plenty of time. You can use `nslookup` to target also some specific DNS server, e.g. `nslookup <domain> 8.8.8.8` will query Google's public DNS server, 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @kim I think something is blocked on work pc, I am not able to ping any website, also `nslookup` fails even for google. I checked the dns name in google public dns, I can see them.

Comment: There are plenty of online tools also that do the same, check out https://mxtoolbox.com/supertoolmobile.aspx for example. It might be that you are behind a proxy and all local traffic should go through it, hence `nslookup` is not working.